# Pass id value from view which is receiving IEnemerable List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to pass id value from my view . I am using Html.ActionLink attribute.
I am performing like this

```
  @foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <div class="grid_1_of_4 images_1_of_4">

        <a href="preview.html"><img src="/@item.p_imageUrl" alt="" /></a>
        <h2>@item.p_name </h2>
        <div class="price-details">
            <div class="price-number">
                <p><span class="rupees">@item.p_price</span></p>
            </div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Add to Cart", "Mobiles", new { id = item.ProductId }, new { @class = "add" })
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

but this doesnot posting it instead get action is calling in controller.How to fix that

Comment: What's the name of the Controller and Action you're trying to link to? Also, is the action expects POST only requests?

Comment: controller name is Products no I have two Actions with same name one with parameter id othe without parameter

Comment: can you show your actions?

Comment: public ActionResult Mobiles()
        {
            var q = from n in db.Mobiles
                    select n;
            return View(q);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Mobiles(int id)
        {
           
            return View(id);
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the one action for both things using optional parameter feature, no need of  making another action:

```
public ActionResult Mobiles(int id=0) 
{ 
// id will be initialized 0 when no id passed to action
if(id > 0)
{

// if id is coming do something here

var q = from n in db.Mobiles 
        where n.ProductId == id
        select n;  

 return View(q);

}

else
{
 var q = from n in db.Mobiles 
         select n;             // id is not passed

 return View(q);
}


}
```